# Approval process Final Rejection email alert not working

Tags: email, key, goole-dmarc-security, dmarc, dkim

I'm building an approval process in which I need a record to be submited to approvers in a queue, and the record gets approved or not. It's a simple one-step approval.

I've set up an email alert for cases when the record is rejected, so its owner knows that it wasn't approved. But I want to use a organization-wide address (like `logistics@company.com`) for this.

The organization already has addresses available for use (for all profiles) (and in use in other processes using scheduled classes), and the address I want to use is registered in the organization-wide address setup page.

The problem is: the email alert seems to work only when the email alert uses the `Current User's email address` option. Any ideas why? Or how can I make the Final Rejection step work with an org-wide address?

Edit:

After @gorav's suggestion, I checkd the email logs on my organization, and some emails did bounce back because of the DMARC policy. The log entries have a message like this:

> 550-5.7.1 Unauthenticated email from thecompany.com is not accepted
>   due to\r\n550-5.7.1 domain's DMARC policy. Please contact the
>   administrator of\r\n550-5.7.1 thecompany.com domain if this was a
>   legitimate mail. Please visit\r\n550-5.7.1
>   https://support.google.com/mail/answer/2451690 to learn about
>   the\r\n550 5.7.1 DMARC initiative.  - gsmtp

So now I want to know: being in a company that has its own domain already defined, and using Google Apps for business, how can I get Salesforce to deliver emails with the addresses I specify? Should I get the DKIM keys for the company's domain? Is it the only step required?

Edit (24/01/2017):

I've requested the keys from the company's domain admin and he provided me with both keys and I imported them to sandbox, but still the emails are bouncing due to DMARC's policy, with the message quoted above. What do I need to do to make Salesforce send emails on behalf of the company domain?

Comment: You might try enabling access to the org wide email address for the users profile, though i Didn't think that was required.

Comment: @gorav The org-wide addresses are available for all users in the organization (Allowed Profiles: All Profiles).

Comment: Have you checked the email logs to ensure that the email really is not sending.   In case there is (something) wrong w the org wide address.

Comment: @gorav I have yet to check the email logs, but I've had the Dev. Console opened during the approval process, and I can see in the logs that some workflow field updates were working (changing the phase to 'Rejected', for instance), but the email alert didn't show up.

Comment: The email alert shows up in dev console when set to current users email but not when set to org wide email? That is odd! Are you in sandbox or prod? You could test deliverability, but I would only do that after checking the email.log file.

Comment: @gorav I think the logs answered the question. I've got a couple of entries with a warning from Gmail (I suppose, since the company is using Google Apps), which says: `550-5.7.1 Unauthenticated email from thecompany.com is not accepted due to\r\n550-5.7.1 domain's DMARC policy. Please contact the administrator of\r\n550-5.7.1 thecompany.com domain if this was a legitimate mail. Please visit\r\n550-5.7.1  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/2451690 to learn about the\r\n550 5.7.1 DMARC initiative. <randomnumbers> - gsmtp`

Comment: Great I'll add an answer!

Comment: This doesn't answer my problem or tells me how to solve the issue. I can contact the domain administrator, great. But I'm fairly sure he doesn't know what to do (an neither do I, in this case). I would like to know what to do in this situation to actually approve an answer.

Comment: depends on how your email server and security is configured. Does the email address work if you send to it from external (personal) email?. Do other org wide addresses work for sending, say from a case? Is this a real org wide address or a fake one?  I can't answer email security questions, I would post it as a separate question, but maybe someone else will be able to take it from here.  Good luck.

Comment: @gorav I've simply registered the addresses on the org-wide addresses setup page. Of course, the administrator of these emails received an email asking permission for Salesforce to send emails on behalf of those addresses, and they all got verified. This might have been rendered useless since Gmail started to comply with DMARC policies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that Salesforce did not specify (or made clear enough) how the DKIM keys work.

To clarify: you **can not** use your own key pair on Salesforce. You must generate the pair on Salesforce and import it to your DNS settings (on your domain).

You can import keys only if they were generated by Salesforce in another organization (for example, you may copy your sandbox's keys to production, since they can use the same keys to sign your emails).

Source: after searching outside SFSE I found [this thread on reddit](https://redd.it/3e7gnq) from a guy who had the same issue/misunderstanding.

Comment: It seems to me that it was @gorav who led you to this solution. Perhaps you might want to consider giving him credit for it in awarding the points to him. Without his help, it doesn't appear to me that you'd have solved your issue. Just something to consider...

Comment: He helped me to find the cause of the issue, but not the solution to the problem.

Comment: You put those points up planning to give them to someone else who helped you, not to give them back to yourself. You can easily change the accepted answer *after* the points have been awarded. Do what you feel is appropriate and fair.

Answer (score 2):

I would first check the email logs to ensure the email is sending properly when using the org wide address.

Then I would test deliverability to ensure you are able to receive email from all of Salesforce email servers

If both tests pass...I'd try using a different org wide address as a last resort, and then would log a case as I'd be out of ideas!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to follow these steps from Google and Salesforce?

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126?hl=en&ref_topic=7279058#authentication

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000232181&language=en_US&type=1

Comment: As I've said in the post I used to answer this question: the problem is that Salesforce didn't made itself clear whether you can use a DKIM key that was generated by you or other third-party or not. And you can't. So you must generate a key in an organization and import the key to your domain.